# Authenticating Zombie.js Browser against Windows Authentication

Tags: node.js, iis, mocha.js, zombie.js

I am able to run my mocha tests using Zombie.js on my local project, but am getting a 401 error while attempting to run it on one of our dev servers.

The dev server this has to go on is Windows Server 2003.  This is an organizational choice rather than my own.

This server has windows authentication for that domain that the app needs to sit on and is the reason I was getting the  401 error.

I tried setting the authentication as suggested by the zombie [docs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API) like so:

```
browser.authenticate().basic("user", "password");
```

This did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just use the https module, cause it seems like it would work just as well.

Comment: I updated my answer above, but I have no choice on the server that the app resides. It has to be on a Windows 2003 Server, running IIS6.

Answer (score 1):

`browser.authenticate().basic()` in Zombie.js carries out [HTTP basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Your site is protected by Windows authentication, i.e. [NTLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237488.aspx). These are different and incompatible protocols. You need to use something like [node-http-ntlm](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm), and either figure out how to interpose it in your tests so that Zombie.js can use the session it establishes, or extend the authentication abilities of Zombie.js to include NTLM.

Comment: Thanks, I hopefully be able to check this out later this week and get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

In addition, the library also provides helper methods for encoding and decoding the headers used during NTLM HTTP authentication. This functionality should presently be considered experimental.

[source](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ntlm)

```
// npm install ntlm request agentkeepalive

var url = "https://.../ews/exchange.asmx"
  , domain = ...
  , username = ...
  , password = ...

var ntlm = require('ntlm')
  , ntlmrequest = require('request').defaults({
    agentClass: require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent
  });

ntlmrequest(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': ntlm.challengeHeader(hostname, domain),
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  ntlmrequest(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': ntlm.responseHeader(res, url, domain, username, password)
    }
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
});
```